# GLFW flicker during resize when rendering from secondary thread

Tags: c, multithreading, opengl, pthreads, glfw

I'm working with GLFW3 + OpenGL in C under Windows 7 64-bit. Since responsive resizing is very important to my application I'm using a secondary thread for logic + rendering loops so rendering won't be interrupted when the UI thread blocks (e.g. when the user holds down the mouse on the window frame).

This works great except that it sometimes causes the contents of my window to flicker while the user is resizing the window. I suspect there's something I still don't fully understand about the consequences of rendering from a secondary thread and the possible interactions with window resizing - this is my first time working with multithreading.

Here's a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <GL/gl3w.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <pthread.h>

GLFWwindow* window;
void *threadfun(void *arg);

int main () {
    pthread_t mythread;
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, &threadfun, (void *)NULL);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) glfwWaitEvents();

    pthread_join(mythread, NULL);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void *threadfun (void *arg) {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gl3wInit();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

(I'm compiling with mingw-w64 `x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1` in case that's relevant.)

Comment: Do you have vsync enabled (using a composited DWM theme, forced on in the driver, etc.)?

Comment: @genpfault As far as GLFW, `glfwSwapInterval` doesn't seem to change anything (issue persists). For all I know my driver does not force vsync, though I am using Areo so that might.

Comment: Do either of these have flicker similar to yours? [vsync on](https://fsrv.dyndns.org/~genpfault/so/42008555/vsync.mp4), [vsync off](https://fsrv.dyndns.org/~genpfault/so/42008555/no-vsync.mp4)

Comment: @genpfault Nah don't see any flicker there. What I'm talking about are random flashes to black.

Comment: @genpfault Here's a quick recording: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ryoomq3iepewdp/2017-02-02%2021-55-27.mp4

Comment: Still happen if you switch to the "Windows 7 Basic" or "Windows Classic" theme?

Comment: @genfault Both in classic and basic it's *much* worse, instead of random flickers, the window contents go completely black as long as I keep moving my mouse when resizing the window.

Comment: IMHO the issues comes from making current the context in a thread that didn't create it.

Comment: I don't understand your strategy. If the gl draws are fast enough there's not problem at all. If they're slow, then the app will become irresponsive, with or without multithreading, because of showing a menu is only done when the GPU has finished. And resizing while the GPU is working doesn't wotk either, you can't stop GPU from drawing. The only idea I see for your case is drawing in chunks and proccess UI between chunks.

Comment: @Ripi2 My strategy is a workaround to an issue with windows caused by how the OS handles window resizing. It will completely block the main thread as long as the user is holding down the mouse on the window border, thus stopping rendering/updates. Using a seperate thread circumvents this.

Comment: Stop updates, right. Using multithreading with shared context may help. I don't know how to set shared context with GLFW. Stop rendering , really?

Comment: Looks as if @genpfault has a sample that doesn't flicker but still redraws while resizing. Could you share that?

Comment: @Ripi2 GLFW allows for shared contexts, will see if that does anything. And yea it's a bit silly, you still get to do stuff when the user moves the mouse, but not while they're holding down in-place. Starting to get why so many linuxers hate windows's guts.

Comment: You may have a big mapped buffer and set a thread to update part of it (the part not currently used for drawing). Draw using base vertex to render only the already updated part. For mouse, set a callback for it, returning quickly if no mouse move is done.

Comment: @Ripi2 If I pass the GL context to the UI thread so it can do an immediate re-draw with the new window dimensions inside the `FramebufferSizeCallback` that seems to prevent flickering from occuring. Requires some additional cross-thread fudgery and creates possible overhead from context un- and re-binding, but it seems to work. Looks like you were right about sharing the context.

Comment: @BDL: [Here's the demo I put together](http://pastebin.com/jrGRcJKN), though it's C++11 rather than C.

Comment: @genpfault In order to make it compile on my system (possibly cus I have mingw64) I had to use this: `g++ cplus.cpp -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lpthread` flicker still occurs. For my example I use `gcc gl3w.c minim.c -o minim.exe -static -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lpthread -Wl,--subsystem,windows`.